# Why does not work import component in project?

Tags: angular

I have core `app.module` and custom component `ErrorsComponent`.

I declarated this component inside `app.module` as:

```
declarations: [AppComponent, ExtractSuffixPipe, KeysPipe, HomeComponent, ErrorsComponent ],
exports: [
    ErrorsComponent
  ],
```

After that I still get an error:

```
Can't bind to 'errors' since it isn't a known property of 'app-errors'.
1. If 'app-errors' is an Angular component and it has 'errors' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Sorry, the component has own module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
import { ReCaptchaModule } from 'angular2-recaptcha';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TranslateModule,
    NgbModule,
    TextMaskModule,
    ReCaptchaModule
  ],

  providers: [
    Captcha,
    ApiUrls,
    Credentials,
    TimerService,
    SmsService,
    UserService,
    LocalService
]

})
export class ErrorsModule { }
```

And `AppModule` is:

import {ErrorsComponent} from "./errors/errors.component";

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, ExtractSuffixPipe, KeysPipe, HomeComponent, ErrorsComponent ],
 exports: [
    ErrorsComponent
  ]...
```

Comment: Which component causes the error (where is `ErrorsComponent` used)? Is it in the same module as `ErrorsComponent`? If not, what do the module imports look like in all related modules?

Comment: In another words add more code.

Comment: The error is about ErrorsComponent, and some piece of code where you use that component and pass it an attribute named errors. But you haven't posted the code of the ErrorsComponent, nor the code using that component and causing the error.

Comment: See my updated question, please

Comment: I have, and it still doesn't contain the relevant code, which is the code of ErrorsComponent, and the HTML template code causing that error.